# Allowing for maximum number of opened accordion sections using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked all over the internet and I can't seem to find a good way to do this.

I've got an accordion menu that I've built primarily using addClass/removeClass and css.  It has special functionality, the accordion tabs open after a delay on mouseover and they open and close on click.  I can currently open all of them at once, but I'd like to limit this to 2 or 3 with the earliest selected panel closing after I hit that limit.  So I'd either need to make the classes numbered and switch them on every action, or perhaps apply a variable that keeps track of the order in which the panels were selected and switch them.

Below is the code I have so far.  I've only been able to get as far as keeping count of how many tabs there currently are open.  Does anyone have an idea as to what the best way to approach this is?

```
var timer;
var counter = 0;

$('li.has-dropdown').mouseenter(function() {

dd_item = $(this);

if(!$(this).hasClass('expand-tab')){
    timer = setTimeout ( function () {
        $(dd_item).addClass('expand-tab');
        counter++;  
        }, 200);    
    };

}).mouseleave(function(){

    clearTimeout(timer);
    console.log(counter);

}).click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('expand-tab')){
        $(this).removeClass('expand-tab');
        counter--;
        console.log(counter);
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('expand-tab');
        console.log(counter);
    }

});
```

Comment: Keep an array of elements; opening one accordion pushes its element to the array and when it reaches 2 or 3 you close the first element in your array ... rinse and repeat

Comment: I thought I might need to something along those lines.  But how do I go about attaching a variable to the element?  Do I use .data or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: You might as well just open 1 at a time all the time. When opening new accordion, close currently opened accordion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a  incrementting `data-index` to each opened tab.

count the tabs on the end of the hover effect, if they are to many, sort them by the index, and hide the lowest/oldest.

```
var timer; 
    var index = 1;

    $('li.has-dropdown').mouseenter(function() {

    dd_item = $(this);

    if(!$(this).hasClass('expand-tab')){
        timer = setTimeout ( function () {
            $(dd_item).addClass('expand-tab');
            $(dd_item).attr('data-index', index++);
            counter++;  
            }, 200);    
        };

    }).mouseleave(function(){

        clearTimeout(timer);
        console.log(counter);

    }).click(function() {

        $(this).taggleClass('expand-tab'); // see jQuery  toggleClass();
        $(this).attr('data-index', index++);//this will add index on closed tabs also.. but it does not matter at the end.
    });


    if($('.expand-tab').length> 3){
        //custom inline sorting function.
        var expanded_tabs = $('.expand-tab').sort(function (a, b) {
          return (parseInt( $(a).attr('data-index')) < parseInt( $(b).attr('data-index')) ? -1 :  1 ;
        });

        //time out .. effect etc.
        expanded_tabs[0].removeClass('expand-tab');
    }
```

P.S I don't like havving  Hover and Click in the same place ... try to separate the events and call a unified `collapseIfToMany` function in on each event

Comment: Thank you d.reav, I've been working on this for a while.  Started out using what you put here, fixed a couple of invalid spots and gradually got to something completely different.  In any case I've back to this and it seems to be so close to working, but expanded_tabs[0].removeClass('expand-tab');   is throwing an "undefined is not a function" error. I'm sure it probably needs a very simple change, but have yet figure that out.

Comment: Figured it out, it was simple.  Thank you!  I'll post the corrected version on here for anyone else that needs to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a corrected version.  I decided to use a variable for the maximum panels opened, this way you don't have to dig if you decide you want to change it, or if you add more to the code.

```
    var timer; 
var index = 1;
var maxOpen = 2;

$('li.has-dropdown').mouseenter(function() {

dd_item = $(this);

if(!$(this).hasClass('expand-tab')){
    timer = setTimeout ( function () {
        $(dd_item).addClass('expand-tab');
        $(dd_item).attr('data-index', index++);
        collapseIfTooMany();
        }, 200);    
    };

}).mouseleave(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
}).click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('expand-tab'); // see jQuery  toggleClass();
    $(this).attr('data-index', index++);//this will add index on closed tabs also.. but it does not matter at the end.
});

function collapseIfTooMany(){
    if($('.expand-tab').length > maxOpen){
        //custom inline sorting function.
        var expanded_tabs = $('.expand-tab').sort(function (a, b) {
          return (parseInt( $(a).attr('data-index')) < parseInt( $(b).attr('data-index'))) ? -1 :  1 ;
        });
        //time out .. effect etc.
        $(expanded_tabs[0]).removeClass('expand-tab');
    }
};
```